# Unexpected token < with React Router & Nginx

Tags: nginx, react-router

Router configuration:

```
const routes =
[
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Layout,
        onEnter: sessionFilter,
        indexRoute:
        {
            component: ActivityIndex,
            onEnter: sessionFilter
        },
        childRoutes:
        [
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginPage
            },{
                path: 'activity-new',
                component: ActivityNew,
                onEnter: sessionFilter
            },{
                path: 'activity-edit/:id',
                component: ActivityEdit,
                onEnter: sessionFilter
            }
        ]
    }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>, Node);
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 5002;
    location / {
        root www/bc;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

All files transpiled with babel(webpack). It works fine when I access `http://server:5002/something` but throws an `Unexpected token <` if I access `http://server:5002/something/1` or `http://server:5002/something/`.

When I looked at the Sources tab in the Developer Tools I noticed that the js file has been returned with the index.html as its content which is caused by the Request URL pointing to `http://server:5002/something/app.js` instead of `http://server:5002/app.js`. Do I need to add something to the configuration to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem in `src` path of your JS file in script tag.

Instead of `<script src="app.js"></script>`, use: `<script src="/app.js"></script>`